# go language equivalent of scanf %[^\n]

Tags: go

for go language

---

`fmt.Scanln("%s",&v)`

---

this should store entire line as string inside v variable right..? but when I am printing I get only the first word and everything after the space is not captured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Scan family of functions scan space-separated tokens.

If you read the [fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scan) documentation it will be obvious why you'll get only the first word of the input.

> Scan scans text read from standard input, storing successive
>   space-separated values into successive arguments. Newlines count as
>   space. It returns the number of items successfully scanned. If that is
>   less than the number of arguments, err will report why.

`bufio.Scan` is what you need.

```
// read standard input as a set of lines.
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text()) // Println will add back the final '\n'
}

if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading standard input:", err)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To read an entire line, you can use the `bufio` package:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    str, _ := r.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

Comment: what significance Scanln have then..? it claims to scan till cr or eof. https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scan

Comment: `Scanln is similar to Scan, but stops scanning at a newline and after the final item there must be a newline or EOF.` It still split by spaces, but do not continue on another line even if there is one.

Comment: so it can be concluded that to scan an entire line with spaces in between words, fmt package has nothing to offer..?

Comment: Not that I know of.